# Possible to crawl/extract a line from a website's robots.txt file?

Tags: r, rvest

I have a website where I want to crawl the robots file present in the root folder.
[www.foo.com/robots.txt](http://www.foo.com/robots.txt)
Here, I want to crawl a specific line [say, line 3] and extract the value [to check whether it contains a Disallow or not]. Is it possible to dos this in RVest?
I'd also like to automatically crawl this page at a scheduled frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easily possible, e.g.:

```
txt <- readLines("https://www.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt")
txt

txt[3] # line 3 of the file
grepl("disallow", txt[3], ignore.case = TRUE) # check for "disallow"
```

To crawl this at a specified time, use a CRON job (Linux) or task scheduler job (Windows).

Comment: Also `txt[[3]] %>% str_detect('Disallow')`

Comment: This works too, here one needs two packages **stringr** and **dplyr**, while the double `[[]]`is not necessary. In short: `library(stringr); library(dplyr); txt[3] %>% str_detect('Disallow')`

Comment: @tpetzoldt  thanks. I've now created an empty data frame and trying to write the value of txt[3] to it. `robotsdata$robots_txt <- txt[3]` doesn't seem to work. Would you be able to help with this? Thank.

Comment: The following works for me with my example above: `robotsdata <- NULL`  to create the empty data frame and then `robotsdata$robots_txt <- txt[3]`

Comment: @tpetzoldt thanks, that worked. I started my empty df with this `robotsdata <- structure(
list(Date = character(), 
robots_txt = character(), 
robots_status = character()),
organic_sessions = integer(),
class = "data.frame")`